# How do I start developing a lens for Unity?

Tags: unity, application-development, development, lenses, scopes

I would like to know how to create one of those lenses for unity. I know how to program. but I don't know where to start. Are there certain libraries I should use or docs that I should read? Are there wiki pages that I can reference?

My google-fu has so far failed me.