# Create my own unity lens

Tags: 11.10, unity, mysql, php, lenses

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I start developing a lens for Unity?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/43077/how-do-i-start-developing-a-lens-for-unity)

Is there any easy way of creating a unity lens without any big programming knowledge? I can code in php, mysql, html and all those web stuff.

I wanna create a lens that connects to my website mysql database and searches for users on my site anyone that can tell me how or show me a tutorial or tell me which stuff i need to learn before creating a lens?