# Is it possible to create a WolframAlpha Lens for Unity

Tags: unity

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I start developing a lens for Unity?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/43077/how-do-i-start-developing-a-lens-for-unity)

Is it possible to create a Wolfram|Alpha search lens for Unity. It would be of great use for many (especially students).

http://products.wolframalpha.com/developers/

Comment: Of course the answer is yes. But is this really a question or is it just a request?.