# Help with creating my own lens

Tags: 11.10, unity, lenses

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I start developing a lens for Unity?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/43077/how-do-i-start-developing-a-lens-for-unity)

I wanna create my first unity lens, but i don't know how it works, i have been trying to follow this tutorial
http://developer.ubuntu.com/resources/technologies/unity/lenses-and-scopes/

but i don't know where to put my files.

they only say where to put the .lens file "/usr/share/unity/lenses/mylens/mylens.lens"
And i don't know what this means

```
DBusName=net.launchpad.Lens.MyLens
DBusPath=/net/launchpad/lens/mylens
```

anyone that could tell me where to put the files or how to export it or what i need to do to get my first lens to work. 
i just wanna create a lens first, and then i can play with the code and make something useful.