# Easy tutorial to create Unity Lens?

Tags: lenses

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I start developing a lens for Unity?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/43077/how-do-i-start-developing-a-lens-for-unity)

Okay, I have been researching all day and night about creating a Unity Lens. Unfortunately, I ended up for nothing. I found most of the tutorials on the web such as [here](http://developer.ubuntu.com/2012/04/how-to-create-a-wikipedia-unity-lens-for-ubuntu/) and [here](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Unity/Lenses) are not helpful at all for a newbie like me! Those tutorials are not clear and lack of details. Is there any other easier tutorials? Thanks in advance.